# iOS determine which button long touch occurs on in imageview

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I have a calculator app and I would like to display different alert view text depending on which calculator button the User long touches.  I have working long touch code.  How can I identify which calculator button the long touch occurs on?

```
-(void)handleLongTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender{

    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    }
    else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){

    // The alert view text should change, depending on which calculator button is long touched
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle: @"I want the alert view text to change according to what calculator button is long touched"
                                                       message: @""
                                                      delegate: self
                                             cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                             otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil]; 


        [alert setTag:1];
        [alert show];

      }
}

// This code only produces a set of X-Y coordinates if the User touches between calculator buttons, not on the button itself
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
    NSLog(@"location.x = %f", location.x);
    NSLog(@"location.y = %f", location.y);
}
```

Comment: Do you have a single tap gesture recognizer (set on a superview), or one for each button? In the first case, you can use `hitTest:withEvent:` to find the view under the tap. In the other case, you can simply use the recognizer's `view` property...

Comment: I currently have a single long touch gesture recognizer.  Are gesture recognizers needed for each button?  I've also been trying to get the tag of the button where the long touch, but without success.  And I've also tried hitTest, but can't detect a button long touch using that.  Will continue working to a solution tomorrow.

Comment: No, you don't *need* one for each button. You *can* have one for each button (in which case you can use the `view` property to find said button). Or if you have a single recognizer, use `locationInView:` to get the location, then `hitTest:withEvent:` to find the view.

Comment: I now have a working solution using view property as you suggested.  I'm almost certain I had tried that yesterday, but couldn't get it to work.  Anyway, thanks for your help with this matter.

Comment: I created an answer with this (actually with both options), feel free to up vote and/or accept it if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

- create one gesture recognizer per view you need to detect the gesture on, all using the same target. Then you can simply use the recognizer's `view` property to find the view (or button) the gesture took place on.
- create a single gesture recognizer (on a superview of the views/buttons you want to detect gestures on), then use `locationInView:` to find the location of the gesture, and `hitTest:withEvent:` to find the specific subview.